# SSD Failing what do i need to look for and what are my options?

Tags: ssd

I have no real knowledge about hardware. My ssd hase failed now and i need to look for another one and preferable a big one (total 250-500 gb). And what would be the price range for it?

This is what i have now: (it's stacked in raid so have 2 of them)

[image]

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about exactly what kind of SSD you want and need. For example, describe the connector (from SSD to you PC), and your budget. Which country you live in would also be nice. Welcome to Hardware Recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is called [mSATA](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/64801/msata).  These are available from every SSD manufacturer but I am very partial to both Samsung and Crucial as I have used many of their products in the past without issue.  I have provided links in order of preference:

- [Samsung 850 EVO 500GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TGIVVKU)
- [Crucial MX200 500GB mSATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RQA6GF0)

Both are priced right around the same price point and both have excellent warranties.

**Will it work in your computer?**

Hardware wise?  Yes.  SATA can address up to 8 EB (Exabytes)  or 8 million TB.

**Will you OS read it?**

Assuming you are using Windows or Linux and not something custom, then NTFS and EXT2/3/4 will address much more than 8EB.  You should be good there as well.

Comment: I also agree and would recommend the 850 Evo due to how reliable and fast it has been. Also worth considering is the Kingston HyperX Savage (http://www.amazon.com/Kingston-HyperX-Savage-SHSS37A-480G/dp/B00W35L2KC/ref=sr_1_5?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1459596834&sr=1-5&keywords=hyperx+ssd) , it is also an extremely good performer.

Comment: @BG_Programmer   I believe the Kingston would be equally good, I just haven't used them (yet) and wanted to limit my answer to what I have actually had my hands on.  Their memory modules are fantastic.  I try to use them for everything

Comment: Definitely. Both the Samsung and Kingston SSD are of such high quality that really it comes down to personal preference of brand etc.

Comment: Those are of 500gb each because my pc has, 2 of them like in the picture that would be 1G that's alot because i also have a normal hard drive of 1g and i don't need really need that amount. Wouldn't a 250(2x) one be alot cheaper then a (500 2x)?

Comment: It would be 1TB.  So, you are putting them in a RAID 0 config for speed.  If you don't need that much, go with the 250GB or the 120GB.  On the link I provided Amazon has a selector for 120, 250, 500, and 1TB.